# Why double clicking opens application but does not load file?

Tags: windows, vb6, registry

I made an application for editing **.cue** files. If I use a **.bat** file containing

```
CueEditor.exe Ah.cue
```

line, it opens application and loads file properly; so it seems command line arguments are able to be passed properly; but double clicking on a **.cue** file opens application without loading file.

**.reg** files which include registry keys which are created by the setup program for registering the application default for **.cue** files are these:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cue]
@="CueFile"
```

and

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CueFile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CueFile\Defaulticon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Cue Editor\\CueEditor.ico\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CueFile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CueFile\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CueFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Cue Editor\\CueEditor.exe\" \"%1\""
```

What is wrong?

By the way, I use Windows XP.

Comment: The %1 in the *command* registry key ensures that the path of the file gets passed as an argument to your program.  But you have to actually write the code to use that argument.  Since you did not mention doing so, forgetting this is the most obvious reason.  Use Command$

Comment: @Hans Passant I answered my question :) I found some weird windows behaviour unexpected and can not be catched easily; at least for me. Thanks; you inspired me to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

At last I found answer after which I had ensured that the registry settings are appropriate. Windows passes the path as string but puts quotation marks of each side like this:

"C:\Documents and Settings\ABC\Desktop\AH.cue"

and if it is being thought that can be used as path like bare **C:\Documents and Settings\ABC\Desktop\AH.cue** string, it does not work. Quotation marks at the ends should have been cleaned first.